# List elements are dependant from each other

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

For some reason, elements in my list(`Maps = new List<CollisionTiles>[]`) are dependant from each other. This list contains information about collision tiles in my game. The problem is, when I set list elements in `Map` list to `Maps[Something]`, `Maps` list is changing too, whenever I do anything with `Map` after assignation.

```csharp
if (mapClass.Maps[3].Count != 0)
{
    mapClass.ClearMap(); // CollisionTiles.Clear(); BackGroundTiles.Clear();
    mapClass.CollisionTiles = mapClass.Maps[3];
    mapClass.BackgroudTiles = mapClass.SpriteMaps[3];
}
if (mapClass.Maps[3].Count == 0)
{
    mapClass.GenerateCustomMap(64, 10, 8, 3, false);
}
```

Comment: Please edit to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question.

Comment: What does mapClass.ClearMap(); do? It seems to me that you are clearing your Maps and then assigning mapClass.Maps[3] which might be empty?

Comment: mapClass.ClearMap(); is clearing mapClass.CollisionTIles and BackgroundTiles lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really difficult to say from the code you've posted but based on your description you might be copying a "reference" to a collection when you intended to copy the collection itself.

For example, let's say to have a list called `a` and you try to make a another list called `b` like this:

```cs
var a = new List<string>();
var b = a;
```

What the above code is actually doing is making `a` and `b` a "reference" to the *same list*.

In other words, if you then did something like this:

```cs
b.Add("item");
```

Now both of the "lists" called `a` and `b` will have the same items in them. That's because they are not actually different lists, they are the same list with two "pointers".

There's a couple of different ways you can correctly copy of a list in C#. One way is to pass the list into the constructor like this:

```cs
var a = new List<string>();
a.Add("item");
var b = new List<string>(a);
```

This will give you two separate lists with that both have an item in them. However, now when you modify either of those lists they won't change together.

A popular (more modern) alternative approach for the code above can be done by `using System.Linq` namespace.

```cs
var a = new List<string>();
a.Add("item");
var b = a.ToList();
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the explonation! Never understood Lists in C#, I definetly should re-read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `mapClass.CollisionTiles` to **reference** to the original `List`.
Therefore, any modifications to the `mapClass.CollisionTiles` changes the original `List` as well. The same goes for `BackgroundTiles`.

To correct this, create new `List` objects when assigning them to the `mapClass`:

```
if (mapClass.Maps[3].Count != 0)
{
    mapClass.ClearMap(); // CollisionTiles.Clear(); BackGroundTiles.Clear();
    mapClass.CollisionTiles = new List<CollisionTiles>(mapClass.Maps[3]);
    mapClass.BackgroudTiles = new List<BackgroudTiles>(mapClass.SpriteMaps[3]);
}
else // this is the only other option from the above if
{
    mapClass.GenerateCustomMap(64, 10, 8, 3, false);
}
```

Please note, I have left the misspelling of `BackgroudTiles`, please correct as necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much!